# Dynamically Adding Traces In Plotly With A Checklist

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset with different age ranges as different columns. I am trying to create dynamic traces for each age range in Plotly to create a comparative bar chart. Moreover, I would like these traces to be connected to a checklist, so I can choose which traces/bars to show up in the resulting graph. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to connect this checklist to the resulting traces in the graph especially since I have other dropdown connected to this graph as well. Here is a sample of the code

```
    Gender=xl['Gender'].unique()
    Age=xl['Age'].unique()
    Activity=xl['Sport'].unique()

app=dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout=html.Div(children=
[html.Div([
    html.H3('Age:', style={'paddingRight': '30px','fontSize':18}),

    dcc.Checklist(
        id='Age',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Age],
    value='18-24' 
)], style={'width':'33%','display':'inline-block'}),

html.Div([
    html.H3('Gender:', style={'paddingRight': '30px','fontSize':18}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Gender', 
        options=[
            {'label': 'Male', 'value': 'Male'},
            {'label': 'Female', 'value': 'Female'}
        ],
        value='Male'
    )], style={'width':'33%','display':'inline-block'}),

html.H3('Activity:', style={'paddingRight': '30px','fontSize':18}), 

dcc.Dropdown(
id='Sport',
options=[
{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Activity],
value='Yoga'
),
],style={'width':'33%','display':'inline-block'}),

html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='linear')]),

html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='linear2')
])])

@app.callback(
 dash.dependencies.Output('linear','figure'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('Gender','value'),
 dash.dependencies.Input('Sport','value'),
 dash.dependencies.Input('Age','value')])

def update_graph(Gender_name,sport_name,age_name):
      xl1=xl[xl['Gender'] == Gender_name]
      xl2=xl1[xl1['Sport'] == sport_name]
      xl3=xl2[xl2['Age'] == age_name]

      Total_x=xl3.Date

      trace1=go.Bar(x=Total_x,y=age_name?,name='6-12')
      trace2=go.Bar(x=Total_x,y=age_name?,name='12-18')
      trace3=go.Bar(x=Total_x,y=age_name,name='18-24')

      Totallayout=go.Layout(xaxis={'title': 'Year'},
                              yaxis={'title': 'Participants'},
                              title= 'Core Player Comparison',
                              hovermode='closest')


      return {'data':[trace2,trace1,trace3],
             'layout':[Totallayout]}
```

I was hoping if someone could help me with the def update graph function so that it could link back to the age dropdown I created while creating different traces as well. If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Sample Dataframe:

Date Sport Gender    Age  Players      Core
  2008  Yoga   Male   6-12  2308.54   692.562
  2008  Yoga   Male  13-17  3551.60  1065.480
  2008  Yoga   Male  18-24  2663.70   799.110
  2008  Yoga   Male  25-34  3551.60  1065.480
  2008  Yoga   Male  35-44  2130.96   639.288

Idea is to create a graph where "Players" or "Core" is the Y Axis and Date is the x axis with Age being the traces.

Comment: This is a little tricky without a sample `df` to use. Can you provide one?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have added a sample data frame in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for updating with the sample`df`. I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but I have data flowing through and charting the `df`. Here is a functional example:

```py
dict_form = {
    'Date': [2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008],
    'Sport': ['Yoga', 'Yoga', 'Yoga', 'Yoga', 'Yoga'],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male'],
    'Age': ['6-12', '13-17', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44'],
    'Players': [2308.54, 3551.60, 2663.70, 3551.60, 2130.96],
    'Core': [692.562, 1065.480, 799.110, 1065.480, 639.288],
}

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_form)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H3('Age:', style={'paddingRight': '30px', 'fontSize': 18}),

        dcc.Checklist(
            id='Age',
            options=[
                {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Age']],
            values=['18-24']
            )
    ]),

    html.Div(children=[
        html.H3('Gender:', style={'paddingRight': '30px', 'fontSize': 18}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='Gender',
            options=[
                {'label': 'Male', 'value': 'Male'},
                {'label': 'Female', 'value': 'Female'}
            ],
            value='Male'
        )
    ], style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.H3('Activity:', style={'paddingRight': '30px', 'fontSize': 18}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Sport',
        options=[
            {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Sport']],
        value='Yoga'
    ),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='linear')]),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='linear2')
    ])
], style={'width': '33%', 'display': 'inline-block'})


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('linear', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Gender', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('Sport', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('Age', 'values')])
def update_graph(gender_name, sport_name, age_name):
    df1 = df[df['Gender'] == gender_name]
    df2 = df1[df1['Sport'] == sport_name]
    df3 = df2[df2['Age'].isin(age_name)]

    total_x = df3.Age

    trace1 = go.Bar(x=total_x, y=df3['Players'], name='Players')
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=total_x, y=df3['Core'], name='Core')

    total_layout = go.Layout(xaxis={'title': 'Year'},
                             yaxis={'title': 'Participants'},
                             title='Core Player Comparison',
                             hovermode='closest')

    return {'data': [trace2, trace1],
            'layout': [total_layout]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

And here is a screencap of the chart:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect. The .isin part was something that completely escaped my mind but the data now shows up in my dashboard. Thanks for everything!